# Regex in java that parses strings that only contain a specific character while allowing spaces

Tags: java, regex, string, search

So i'm currently trying to search for strings that have the comma `,` in it, while allowing spaces in between. For example, `a ,,,,     , ,, ,  , ,, b c    d` will have the entirety between `a` and `b` be highlighted, but not between `b` and `c`, or `c` and `d`.

currently, I have regex like this:

```
([]\\,+[\s]?)+
```

that highlights all spaces and commas, but it will even highlight the spaces between b and c, and c and d. How do i make it so that it only highlights where there are commas?

also, this specific regex does not work in Java. Where do I have to escape character to make it functional in Java as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for regex like

```
\s*,[\s,]+
```

which in Java needs to be written as String `"\\s*,[\\s,]*"` (`\` is special character in String as well as in regex and to create such literal you need to escape it by writing it as `"\\"`).

This regex will accept only text which contains of spaces and commas, but must have at least one comma, so parts between `b` and `c`, or `c` and `d` shouldn't be matched because they don't contain at least one comma.